# Passing value to button click event

Tags: python-3.x

The code below creates 10 buttons. When user clicks the button, we need to know which button was clicked.

```
import tkinter as t

def click_button(number):
    print("you clicked %d" % number)

root = t.Tk()

for number in range(0, 10):
    btn = t.Button(root, text=number, padx=15, command=lambda: click_button(number))
    btn.grid(row=0, column=number)

root.mainloop()
```

1. When I click any button, I always get 9. Why is that?
2. Is there a better/alternative way to address this problem?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `lambda number: click_button(number)..`? What does the documentation say about `command=`?

Comment: Ignore my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the closure over `number` is by reference given a simple loop test, however I'm not sure this is correct behavior.

This works using `partial` which I have no doubt captures the value of `number` at the time of constructing the partial:

```
import functools as fc
import tkinter as t


def click_button(number):
    print("you clicked %d" % number)


root = t.Tk()

for number in range(0, 10):
    btn = t.Button(
        root,
        text=number,
        padx=15,
        command=fc.partial(click_button, number))
    btn.grid(row=20, column=number)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @dhiman Not sure either, I would expect the lambda declaration closes over (`closure`) number at the time

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass number as a lambda parameter.
Try:

```
command=lambda param = number : click_button(param)
```

Some clarification about the way lambda function "captures" local variable can be found here:
[What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)
and here:
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-do-lambdas-defined-in-a-loop-with-different-values-all-return-the-same-result

In a nutshell, by passing number as a parameter to the lambda, you ensure a copy of number will be performed for iterated number value. If you do not pass it as parameter, all lambda functions "number" point to the same variable ( loop number) which is evaluated only when the lambda function is called. At the time it is called number value is "9". This is very different from C++ where the scope of a "for loop" variable is the loop itself. In python the variable of the loop exists as long as someone (here the lambdas) references it.

Comment: So, Python lambda's don't close over scope variables, you have to explicitly assign it as the input arg?

Comment: This also works.. but I don't understand the reasoning. Any references to read?